# Why is my Views row template not loaded?

Tags: 7, views

I am using [Views 3](https://www.drupal.org/project/views).

I have created my view and get these theme suggestions:

[image]

As you can see I created a `--presse-page.tpl.php` file bold marked in the second block. It works fine, but I need to style only the rows. So I created a `views-view-fields--presse.tpl.php` file, but if I rescan the theme, it does not appear.

Why not?

Answer (score 1):

Your file should be called **views-view-field--presse.tpl.php**. field without an 's' not views-view-fields--presse.tpl.php file

Comment: no, stil not working :(

Answer (score 1):

check which theme you selected and make sure that same theme is affecting the page.[image]

And check filename present in the theme info and tempate filename are same
also clear cache then rescan it. 
May be it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You have to clear the cache when changing any template file